# Google Maps Cluster Item Marker - Update Marker Icon

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to utilize the clustering from Google Maps Android API utility library. So far its working fine. One problem however arise which I don't see a apparent solution for. If I need to update an marker icon in my map view - how to do this? Since the switch to the clustering approach I don't have the Marker objects anymore and can't simply use `setIcon`. Also I would need to determine if the target marker is currently in a cluster (in this case it would not make sense to update the icon because it represents the whole cluster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way in `DefaultClusterRenderer` using the `getMarker` method. It seems to return Marker objects for single items so the clusters are not affected.